# C++ class initialization of multiple data members with one assignment

Tags: c++, constructor, casting

Assume I have the following class that is more or less a generic mechanism to store arbitrary values/types in the same class (this is in the context of a database)

```
class RawStruct {
private:
            uint16_t value1;    /// value[0..1]
            uint16_t value2;    /// value[2..3]
            uint16_t value3;    /// value[4..5]
            uint16_t value4;    /// value[6..7]
            uint8_t flags;      /// 
            uint8_t padding;    /// unused.

INLINE_HOST_DEVICE RawStruct(const int64_t value) : RawStruct(toFlags(XMLDatatype::xsd_long),(uint64_t)value) {}


INLINE_HOST_DEVICE RawStruct(uint8_t flags, uint64_t value) {setValue(flags,value);}

 INLINE_HOST_ONLY void setValue(uint8_t flags, uint64_t value) {

                    *((uint64_t*)&this->value1) = value;

                    /*
                    *((uint16_t*)&this->value1) = (value);
                    *((uint16_t*)&this->value2) = (value) >> 16;
                    *((uint16_t*)&this->value3) = (value) >> 32;
                    *((uint16_t*)&this->value4) = (value) >> 48;
                    */
                    this->flags = flags;
                    this->padding = 0;
                }
```

Now some code that invokes the above:

```
int value=42;
char* data = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(RawStruct));
RawStruct* rsArray = (RawStruct*)data;

rsArray[0] = RawStruct((long) value);
```

Now my problem: When compiling a complex piece of code that more or less behaves like the invocation above I get some incorrect value being stored in the RawStruct array. This only happens in our testing on the ARM platform with optimizations (-O3). On X86 all our testing passes. They also pass on arm when using debug mode (-g and no optimizations).

My question would be : Are we violating some rule inside that setValue method by looking at the four uint16_t-s as one big uint64_t ?

Do I hit maybe some incorrect code generation by the compiler ?

The code works fine if I comment the current cast/assignment and replace with the four individual assignments that are commented out above (inside setValue() helper).

Comment: *"Are we violating some rule"* - yes, the strict aliasing rule. `value1` is not a `uint64_t` so treating it as such is wrong

Comment: You should use: `Rawstruct(uint8_t flags_, uint64_t value) : value1(value), value2(value >> 16), value3(value >> 32), value4(value >> 48), flags(flags) {}` and define `padding` as `uint8_t padding{0};`. Check if the compiler doesn't optimize that into a single 64bit write anyway.

Comment: Could you use a union?

Comment: @Matt • a `union` in C++ does not allow writing to one union member variable, and reading from another union member variable.

Comment: @Eljay per the standard yes but "Many compilers implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read inactive members of a union."

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
*((uint64_t*)&this->value1) = value;
```

has undefined behavior. `&this->value1` is a pointer to a `uint16_t`. You cannot use a pointer of type `uint64_t*` to write to that `uint16_t` object.

It violates the aliasing rules and even if they weren't a thing, the C++ object model wouldn't have any concept of writing to multiple consecutive objects in one access like this.

The alignment requirements of the types might also be a problem. `this->value1` may not be aligned correctly for a `uint64_t`, causing undefined behavior as well (at least in general, probably not with the `malloc`).

And even further, there is no guarantee that there won't be padding between the members in general, although you would probably know if this was the case based on the target ABI.

If you find yourself using C-style casts in C++, rethink what you are doing. If it can't be done with a C++-style `static_cast` instead, it is very likely leading to UB (and even `static_cast` allows some potentially dangerous cast).

For example `(uint64_t)value` can also be written as `static_cast<uint64>(value)` and will work, while `static_cast<uint64_t*>(&this->value1)` will fail, which should be considered a warning that there is danger in the cast. (C++-style would require `reinterpret_cast` here.)

Also, `malloc` in C++ code is very likely wrong and leading to UB as well. It should be `new` (or rather `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector` or some equivalent) instead. (In your particular example here it turns out to be fine, but if your class wasn't that trivial, it wouldn't.)

Comment: I fixed the malloc; we do have the cast; The focus is on why I can't see the four uint16 as one uint64

Comment: @GabrielT • four `uint16` are not one `uint64`.  They're different types.  C++ is (ostensibly) a type safe language.  There are very limited cases where type spoofing is allowed, and this isn't one of those limited cases.